# CURL modifying request headers

Tags: php, curl

I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm sending an API request, via CURL, using PHP. The headers to the third party application need to be as follows:

```
    $headers = array( 
        "content-type: application/json",
        "Accept: application/json"
    );
```

The CURL request is initialised and sent as follows:

```
    // 1. initialize
    $ch = curl_init();

    // 2. set the options, including the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->sendPropertyUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $this->certPath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $this->certPath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $this->certPassword);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $propertyDataString);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // 3. execute and fetch the resulting HTML output
    $rightmoveResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    $output = json_decode($rightmoveResponse, true);
```

However if I trap the header info actually sent in the CURL request the output is as follows:

```
    POST /v1/property/sendpropertydetails HTTP/1.1
    Host: adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com
    Accept: */*
    Content-Length: 1351
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Expect: 100-continue
```

Can anyone explain why CURL has modified the Accept and Content-Type parameters?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is defined by `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` instead of `CURLOPT_HEADER`.

From [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> **CURLOPT_HEADER**    TRUE to include the header in the output.
>
> **CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER**    An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array`('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`

See this [user note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#80271) about using it.

Answer (score 0):

You used `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);` which sets the content-type. Instead use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

This is in addition to what @Alan Machado said.